# Sharepoint 2019 onPostRender is not fired when accessing Site or SubSite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

In Sharepoint 2013 I registered a function to onPostRender event and it worked properly both when accessing Site or SubSite and when accessing Document Library.

In Sharepoint 2019 Something get wrong, and the onPostRender event is fired only when accessing Document Library but not when accessing Site or SubSite.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

This is the registration code:

```
function registerTemplate
{
    var vc = {};
    vc.Templates = {};
    vc.OnPostRender = onPostRender;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(vc);
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerTemplate, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

Thanks a lot !